# Bergomi's model normalisation

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-processes, forward, mathematics

On his book https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B019FNKQS8/ref=dp_kinw_strp_1 Bergomi derives a multifactor mean reversible volatility of the volatility such that :

\begin{equation*}
d \xi_{t}^{T}=\omega(\tau) \xi_{t}^{T} d X_{t}
\end{equation*}

$\xi_{t}^{T}$ is the instantaneous forward variance.
$\omega(\tau)$ is a weighted average of forward volatility at time $t$ for an horizon of $T$ .

$X_{t}$ is a mean revertible OU process with length $t$ such :
\begin{align}
d X_t = -k \omega X_t dt +  \omega d W_t \, , \, X_0 = 0 
\end{align}
We also have  $\log(\xi_{t}^{T}) \sim N\Big(\log(\xi_{0}^{T})- \frac{1}{2}\int^{t}_{0}\omega^{2}(T -s ) d s , \int^{t}_{0} \omega^{2}(T -s ) d s\Big)$.The proof is trivial and similar to the one of the Black and Scholes.

The equation becomes equal to :

\begin{align}
d \xi_{t}^{T} = w e^{-k(T-t)}\xi_{t}^{T} dX_t \label{eq:eq46}
\end{align}

when setting $w$ = $2v$ with $v$ being the volatility of the volatility(which is more natural than the volatility of the variance )

What I don't understand is when translating to multifactor model with $N$ Brownian motions such :

$$
d \xi_{t}^{T}=\omega \alpha_{w} \xi_{t}^{T} \sum_{i} w_{i} e^{-k_{i}(T-t)} d X_{t}^{i}
$$
where $\alpha_{w}$ is a normalizing factor and I guess $w_{i}$ is the covariance of the OU processes.However I am not sure of that claim.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\omega &=2 \nu \\
\alpha_{w} &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{i j} w_{i} w_{j} \rho_{i j}}}
\end{aligned}
$$
I don't understand why and how we used such normalisation because at the end we will have :

\begin{equation}
\xi_{t}^{T}=\xi_{0}^{T} \exp ( \sum_i \omega e^{-k_{i}(T-t)} X_{it}- \omega^{2}\sum_{ij}\frac{e^{-(k_{i}+k_{j})(T-t)}}{2} E[X_{it}X_{jt}])
\end{equation}

and will afterward retrieve the initial mean reversible SDE of the lognormal volatility of the variance such :

\begin{equation}
\omega(T-t) = \sum_i e^{-k_{i} (T-t) } \omega d W_t
\end{equation}

I also find other illustrations on internet that write the multifactor model SDE such :

\begin{equation}
d \xi_t^T  = w \xi_t^T \sum_k \lambda_{kt}^T \xi_t^T dW_t^k
\end{equation}

However I do not understand what is $ \lambda_{kt}^T$ and how the extrapolation has been made from the one factor model .